# Split a set of data to massives and find maximum for each

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

I have a set of data looking like this:

```
1   0.1
2   0.23
3   0.05
5   0.73
6   0.40
7   0.34
10  0.11
11  0.45
12  0.68
```

I need to split the set of data to massives using the rule that the next value in the first column is bigger than previous one by more than `1`, and find the maximum values in the second column for every of the massives.
So the outcome in this case would be:

```
1   0.1
5   0.73
12  0.68
```

I tried couple things with `NR` parameter but apparently didn't succeed.
So I will appreciate any help or advice you can give.

Comment: Surely the first output line should be: `2  0.23`?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
     $1 > count + 1{
         print max_n, max
         max = $2 - 1
     }
     max < $2{
         max = $2
         max_n = $1
     }
     {
        count = $1
     }
     END{
         print max_n, max
     }' file
```

Comment: I might be doing something wrong but it doesn't really work in my hands. Always giving error: awk: ./my.awk:2: awk '
awk: ./my.awk:2:     ^ invalid char ''' in expression
awk: ./my.awk:2: awk '
awk: ./my.awk:2:     ^ syntax error

Comment: @Kredo Reread script carefully: there is no `""` char in it

Comment: it was ' ' ' not " "  meaning that ' - is considered as invalid char. Have you tried running it? Did you save it as a separate awk script and then ran in a bush as following: ScriptName.awk file1 > file2 ? or you have done it in a different way? Could you provide a bit more details please?  I desperately need it working :(

Comment: ok looks like everything is working just fine after I removed ' chars from the beginning and end. Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: @Kredo Did you use right sha-bang `#!//usr/bin/awk -f`? Sure in the case you should store just all between `'` excluded.